# RAID card not detected

Tags: hardware-rec, hardware-raid

I recently picked up an ASUS P8B-E/4L motherboard to replace a S3210SH (8GB RAM limit). My brother donated an old LSI SAS3444e(1068e) RAID controller which is meant to drive the 6SAS 2TB HDD in my HotSwap rack.

The controller works with the S3210sh. The BIOS detects the card and the card's BIOS is accessible. The ASUS board doesn't see card in BIOS and neither does the "Device Manager" of "Win Sever 2016".

The card works on a GigaByte H97Gaming3 and G31MXs2 boards. PCIe slots work as tested with GFX card. Latest motherboard BIOS 6801 flashed. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try it in a different slot?